# Call dynamic types' interface method

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a common module using Go interface. It results in an error:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is main.AmazonOrder, not main.OrderMapper
```

Code:

```golang
package main

type AmazonOrder struct {
    OrderId string
    ASIN string
}

func (o AmazonOrder) Generalise() *Order {
    return &Order{
        ChannelOrderId: o.OrderId,
    }
}

type EbayOrder struct {
    OrderId string
    SKU string
}

func (o EbayOrder) Generalise() *Order {
    return &Order{
        ChannelOrderId: o.OrderId,
    }
}

type Order struct {
    ID string
    ChannelOrderId string
}

type OrderMapper struct {
    Generalise func() *Order
}

var orderFactory = map[string]func() interface{} {
    "amazon": func() interface{} {
        return AmazonOrder{}
    },
    "ebay": func() interface{} {
        return EbayOrder{}
    },
    "vanilla": func() interface{} {
        return Order{}
    },
}

func main() {
    orderType := "amazon"

    initialiseOrder := orderFactory[orderType]
    anOrder := initialiseOrder()

    // Unmarshal from json into anOrder etc.. here.

    theOrder := anOrder.(OrderMapper).Generalise()

    println(theOrder.ChannelOrderId)
}
```

In plain sight logic, this should work fine. But, definitely I'm misunderstanding the type conversion in Go. TIA for clarifying what it is.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tHCzKGzEloL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use interface, not a struct with function field, i left comments around the ganges.

```
// OrderMapper is probably ment to be an interface. You can convert interface
// to struct only if its the original one. Though you need to convert it into iterface in 
// your case because type of return value is variable. As all orders implement 
// 'Generalise' and you are planing to convert empty interface to OderMapper why not just 
// return order mapper right away? also best practice to name your interface, with just 
// one method, is methodName + 'er' so Generalizer.
type OrderMapper interface {
    Generalise() *Order
}

/* alternative
    var orderFactory = map[string]func() OrderMapper{
    "amazon": func() OrderMapper {
        return AmazonOrder{OrderId: "amazonOrderID"}
    },
    "ebay": func() OrderMapper {
        return EbayOrder{}
    },
    "vanilla": func() OrderMapper {
        return Order{}
    },
}
*/
var orderFactory = map[string]func() interface{}{
    "amazon": func() interface{} {
        return AmazonOrder{OrderId: "amazonOrderID"} // i added a value to verify correctness
    },
    "ebay": func() interface{} {
        return EbayOrder{}
    },
    "vanilla": func() interface{} {
        return Order{}
    },
}

func main() {
    orderType := "amazon"

    initialiseOrder := orderFactory[orderType]
    anOrder := initialiseOrder()

    // Unmarshal from json into anOrder etc.. here.

    // alternative: theOrder := anOrder.Generalise()
    theOrder := anOrder.(OrderMapper).Generalise()

    println(theOrder.ChannelOrderId == "amazonOrderID") // true
}
```

Comment: Aha. I learnt about `interface` in Go today. Cheers.

Comment: I'm not returning `OrderMapper` because I need to unmarshal properties from a json string into each type before calling `Generalise`. And, yes, that is why I ran into this problem.